# liquibase subselect - how does one build the XML format?

Tags: liquibase, subquery

I would like to use a subselect in a  in Liquibase. Does Liquibase support SubSelects other than embedded SQL (i.e. the sql tag) ? If so, can you point me to how to build something like a  please?

Comment: Why?? Liquibase is a tool for managing database schemas. It's not an ORM.

Answer (score 9):

I assume you mean doing a subselect in an insert or update or create tag.

You cannot use sub-selects in the createTable but you can use the valueComputed tags in  and . For example:

```
<update tableName="person">
    <column name="employees" valueComputed="(select count(*) from person where manager=person.id)"/>
</update>
```

NOTE: If you don't want to drop all the way down to a <sql> tag for commands not handled by the standard XML tags (like subselects in createTable) You can also use  to introduce changes and additions to what liquibase can generate from the XML.